# Bind ListView to a List of objects three levels deep

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a Windows Phone 8.1 application (non SL) and I have the following model:

```
Quiz
    -- Question
        -- Text
        -- Options
            Options 1 (name, value)
            Options 2 (name, value)
            Options 3 (name, value)
```

In my XAML page, I have a ListView. I am attempting to bind the list of options to it, like so:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateOptions">
        <TextBlock Text="{ Binding Name }" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Question.Options}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TemplateOptions}"></ListView>
```

But this isn't working! When I run the application, the list is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Your ItemsSource appears to be bound to the wrong property. It should be bound to your collection of questions.

Comment: @JamesPack I made a correction to the code. I only have one `Question` under `Quiz` and a collection of `Options` under `Question`

Comment: Are you getting any binding errors in the output window? What color is the background of your page?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work like this:

CodeBehind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    public class Quiz
    {
        public Question Question { get; set; }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var options = new List<Option>();
        options.Add(new Option { name = "foo", value = "bar" });
        options.Add(new Option { name = "foo", value = "bar" });
        options.Add(new Option { name = "foo", value = "bar" });
        options.Add(new Option { name = "foo", value = "bar" });

        var question = new Question
        {
            Text = "Question 1",
            Options = new ObservableCollection<Option>(options)
        };


        this.DataContext = new Quiz { Question = question };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
    /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

public class Question
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Option> Options { get; set; }
}

public class Option
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }

}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateOptions">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="White">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Question.Options}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TemplateOptions}"></ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That works for me too, but that isn't 3 levels deep, only 2. How would I get it to work like I have? `Quiz` > `Question` > `List<Options>`

Comment: I must be misunderstanding what you are asking. Sorry.

Comment: Your question says 2 levels deep.

Comment: The list is two levels deep, but the objects sitting in the list are three levels deep if that makes sense? Sorry, it is my probably my fault. I'll update title.